# For Each loop in JavaScript are making me mad

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is pretty simple. 
I'm trying to update a list of objects (localDatz) with another list of objects received after an AJAX request (data). 
So It consists in two loops.. But when I try to update two objects, only one object is updated. There is something I really don't understand.
Any help ?

```
    // fetch the localdata first
            var localData = getAll();

// Loop through my 'localData'
$.each(localData.features, function(index,feature){

        // Loop through the new data that are received
        $.each(data.features, function(){
            newFeature = this;

            if (feature.properties.id==newFeature.properties.id){

            // i think here is the problem..but can't figure out how to fix it
            // I remove the old feature and push the new one
            localData.features.splice(index,1);                                                                   
            localData.features.push(newFeature);


            }

    });

});
```

Comment: If you are not relying on `newFeature` being appended to the **end** of the array, couldn't you simplify it to `localData.features.splice(index, 1, newFeature);`?

Comment: I tried with your method, It works great! Thank you ! But what does it really change between this and the push method  ?

Comment: The difference, as in freakish's answer below, is that `push` appends elements to the end of the array, whereas `splice` adds at the specified index. However, you can simply overwrite the item directly using freakish's answer without using `splice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modyfing the list which you loop over with this code:

```
if (feature.properties.id==newFeature.properties.id){
    localData.features.splice(index,1);
    localData.features.push(newFeature);
}
```

and not only modyfing the list entries, but the order as well (you push to the end of the list), which messes up `.forEach` loop. Use simply:

```
if (feature.properties.id==newFeature.properties.id){
    localData.features[ index ] = newFeature;
}
```

There is no need for using `.splice` at all.

Comment: Out of interest, is there a performance benefit to overwriting the item directly instead of using `splice`? I'd imagine there is, as there are less operations involved.

Comment: Hello freakish, thanks very much for your explanation. (I am really impressed about the responsiveness of Stackoverflow!)  I wasn't aware that push method could messup the forEach iterator. I tried your code and It solves my problem. Thanks again for your help. much appreciated. Gallien

Comment: @ChrisFrancis Actually there is only a slight performance benefit. Indeed, `splice` does more operations, but these are done on pointers so they are very fast.